# Searching for the name of this group.

Tags: group-theory

I am looking for the name of an infinite group defined by the presentation

$\langle \sigma_1,\sigma_2 | \sigma_i \sigma_j ... \sigma_k = (\sigma_k ... \sigma_j \sigma_i)^{-1} \rangle$   .

Does such a group exist?

Comment: What do you mean with the subscripts in the relations?  Since you only have two generators, do you mean $\langle \sigma_1, \sigma_2 \mid \sigma_1 \sigma_2 = (\sigma_2 \sigma_1)^{-1} \rangle$?

Comment: Is it obvious that such a group is infinite?

Comment: @Adam Saltz: it's hard to say because we have no idea what the group is! But probably yes, because any group defined by a presentation with more generators than relations is infinite (it has infinite abelianization).

Answer (score 4):

There's a chance that the equation $\sigma_i\sigma_j\dots\sigma_k=(\sigma_k\dots\sigma_j\sigma_i)^{-1}$ is intended to indicate a whole family of relations, one for each choice of the sequence $i,j,\dots,k$.  In that case, looking first at sequences of length $1$, we get that each $\sigma_i$ has order $2$.  That implies all the other relations, so the group $\langle\sigma_1,\sigma_2\mid\sigma_i\sigma_j\dots\sigma_k=(\sigma_k\dots\sigma_j\sigma_i)^{-1}\rangle$ is just the free product of two copies of the two-element group.

On the other hand, there's also a chance that the equation $\sigma_i\sigma_j\dots\sigma_k=(\sigma_k\dots\sigma_j\sigma_i)^{-1}$ is intended to indicate just a single relation, corresponding to one sequence $i,j,\dots,k$.  In that case, the group depends on just what sequence that is, and I doubt that it has a special name except in some particularly simple cases (for example, if $i,j,\dots,k$ is a sequence of length $1$, then this would be the free product of an infinite cylcic group and a group of order $2$).